# Storage of BSONObj in container: can't get the fields

Tags: c++, mongodb, boost, vector, bson

I use mongodb c++ driver to obtain some records from database `mydb`, collection `mycollection`. 
When I get a record with `mongo::BSONObj current_obj=cursor->next();` and then try to get some field `field1` using `getField` or `getFieldDotted` (field is present in the record), it always succeeds (and prints `"got the field"`- see code below). I've also checked the contents of `BSONElement` returned: they are fine.

Then I push back all found records as `BSONObj`'s into a vector (`QVector` or `boost::container::vector`), and return the vector from a query.

Later, in other function, I iterate over `BSONObj`'s from that vector. Calling `getField` or `getFieldDotted` here throws out an exception with some probability: e.g., 40% of program runs no exception occurs (prints out `"got the field from vector"` 10 times), 60% of program runs I get `Caught BSONElement: bad type 88` (the last `int` value could be different depending on current `BSONObj`: may be `-120`, `110`, `126`, or some other. However, it preserves on every record).

Why does it happen?

The code:

```
boost::container::vector<mongo::BSONObj> makeQuery(QString query)
{
    std::auto_ptr <mongo::DBClientCursor> cursor = my_connection->query("mydb.mycollection", mongo::fromjson(query.toStdString()));
    //...(checking getLastError())

    //QVector<mongo::BSONObj> bsonobjects;
    boost::container::vector<mongo::BSONObj> bsonobjects;

    while (cursor->more())
    {
        mongo::BSONObj current_obj=cursor->next();
        for (int ii=0; ii<10; ii++)
        {
            current_obj.getField("field1");
            std::cout<<"---got the field---\n";
        }
        bsonobjects.push_back(current_obj);
    }
    return bsonobjects;
}

void processBSONObjVector()
{
    //....

    //(below we call makeQuery)
    try
    {
        //QVector<mongo::BSONObj> objects=makeQuery(query_string);
        boost::container::vector<mongo::BSONObj> objects=makeQuery(query_string);
        for (int i=0; i<objects.size; i++)
                for (int ii=0; ii<10; ii++)
                {
                    objects[i].getField("field1");
                    std::cout<<"---got the field from vector---\n";
                }
    }
    catch (const mongo::DBException &e)
    {
        std::cout << "Caught " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

It seems like a heisenbug occurs, something with memory: if (happily) `BSONObj` is not rewritten by other data, the value of `field1` could be taken.
`BSONObj` in vector could be corrupted as like as it is out of context and no smart ptrs are left.

Is `BSONObj` not copyable with `BSONObj(const BSONObj & other)`?

The documentation proposes to pass `BSONObj` by value - it is a case when I use `push_back`(object), isn't it?

---

Also, maybe irrelevant, there's a questionable code when I open the connection (not sure it is memory-safe to perform `dynamic_cast<mongo::DBClientConnection*>` of `mongo::DBClientBase*`, `DBClientBase` is abstract):

my_connection is an established connection to mongodb:

```
//... (make a connection)
mongo::client::initialize(); 
//...
my_connection = dynamic_cast<mongo::DBClientConnection*> (connection_string.connect(errmsg)); //connection_string is valid mongo::ConnectionString
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[That link](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongodb-user/1249mpr2gy/how-can-i-create-a-a-map-of-bsonobjbuilder-using-std-map) gave an impact for an answer.

For c++-0x (`#if __cplusplus >= 201103L`), `BSONObj` have move constructor and explicitly created copy constructor:

```
BSONObj(const BSONObj&) = default;
```

For c++ version lower than c++0x, default copy ctor also will be created.

But BSONObj object contains pointers (!!!) and internal object (buffer):
`const char* _objdata;`
`SharedBuffer _ownedBuffer;`
SharedBuffer also contains pointer `boost::intrusive_ptr _holder` with no copy constructor (except default).

So not contents are copied, but pointers.

[legacy-1.0.5 BSONObj.h](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/0d0f2ce0cfe99c34a8e6370a41c46838c5582b7a/src/mongo/bson/bsonobj.h):

```
     BSONObj& operator=(BSONObj otherCopy) {
        this->swap(otherCopy);
        return *this;
    }

    /** Swap this BSONObj with 'other' */
    void swap(BSONObj& other) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(_objdata, other._objdata);
        swap(_ownedBuffer, other._ownedBuffer);
    }
```

Again, **pointers** are swapped.

**So, we can't copy `BSONObj` with copy ctor or `operator=`.**

It should be properly reflected in documentation, [like for `BSONObjBuilder`](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongodb-user/1249mpr2gy/how-can-i-create-a-a-map-of-bsonobjbuilder-using-std-map), if it is done intentionally.

Two solutions:

1) Create smart pointer on `BSONObj` in `makeQuery()` and return it (better).

2) Work with `BSONObj` in `makeQuery()` context (worse: it may be used only for short and not repeated work on `BSONObj`, otherwise leads to code unreadability and non-reusability).

EDIT1: ***Creating smart pointer and returning it results in the same error***.
**The answer** is within [the code comments](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/0d0f2ce0cfe99c34a8e6370a41c46838c5582b7a/src/mongo/bson/bsonobj.h):

> OWNED CASE
>
> If the BSONObj owns the buffer, the buffer can be shared
>   among several BSONObj's (by assignment). In this case the buffer is
>   basically implemented as a shared_ptr.
>
> UNOWNED CASE
>
> A BSONObj can also point to BSON data in some other data structure it does not "own" or free later. For example, in a memory mapped file.  In this case, it is important the original data stays in scope for as long as the BSONObj is in use.  If you think the original data may go out of scope, call BSONObj::getOwned() to promote your BSONObj to having its own copy. On a BSONObj assignment, if the source is unowned, both the source and dest will have unowned pointers to the original buffer after the assignment. If you are not sure about ownership but need the buffer to last as long as the BSONObj, call getOwned().

`copy()` method works as well as getOwned(), providing owned copy of `BSONObj`.
**Return of owned copy results in no error.**

```
mongo::BSONObj* curr_elem=new mongo::BSONObj();
(*curr_elem)=cursor->next().getOwned(); //or: next().copy();
```

Comment: Good find. You can __bet__ this is by design (of course). And the semantics are pretty well described [`copy()`](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_b_s_o_n_obj.html#a0ac108a078b777b55595f3524d2efc25) and [`getOwned()`](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_b_s_o_n_obj.html#a08d8bc5c50a98a43863342b45e157122). Also "So, we can't copy BSONObj with copy ctor or operator=" is simply a false claim. You can. It doesn't do what you hoped it would do in this occcasion

Comment: @sehe: Just found `copy()` and `getOwned()` and edited the answer and now I see your comment!

Comment: @sehe: we can read "If the BSONObj owns the buffer, the buffer can be shared among several BSONObj's (by assignment)." But in the code we see: `swap(_ownedBuffer, other._ownedBuffer);` with std::swap. _ownedBuffer is a `SharedBuffer` object, as I understand, `other` will not share the same buffer with `this` after swap (other will possess the contents of `_ownedBuffer` before swap). Note, the code you provided (the docs for mongodb 26compat version, [generated on 5 may 2014](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/)) uses _holder = rRHS._holder; instead of swap!)